# Swift App Crashes on Startup on Ipad... Not in simulators

Tags: ios, ipad, swift

Good Day,

My Swift App runs fine in the simulators, but on my physical IPAD it crashes immediately after startup. I tested it on iOS 7 and 8 in the Ipad. This seems related to the Swift Standard Library?? Oh and yes I did delete the App and reran it.

Can anyone please suggest a course of action?

The Crash report is :
dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPC10Foundation15NSFastGeneratorSs13GeneratorType
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/083E8585-EBBF-43D5-B7D9-30544C689ED4/Client.app/Client
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/083E8585-EBBF-43D5-B7D9-30544C689ED4/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/083E8585-EBBF-43D5-B7D9-30544C689ED4/Client.app/Client

The execution stack : 
2.
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x1200e5088:  brk    #3

1.
dyld`_dyld_start:
0x1200e5000:  mov    x28, sp
0x1200e5004:  and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x1200e5008:  movz   x0, #0
0x1200e500c:  movz   x1, #0
0x1200e5010:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-16]!
0x1200e5014:  mov    fp, sp
0x1200e5018:  sub    sp, sp, #16
0x1200e501c:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x1200e5020:  ldr    x1, [x28, #8]
0x1200e5024:  add    x2, x28, #16
0x1200e5028:  adrp   x4, #-4096
0x1200e502c:  mov    x4, x4
0x1200e5030:  adrp   x3, #163840
0x1200e5034:  ldr    x3, [x3, #880]
0x1200e5038:  sub    x3, x4, x3
0x1200e503c:  mov    x5, sp
0x1200e5040:  bl     0x4c
0x1200e5044:  mov    x16, x0
0x1200e5048:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x1200e504c:  cmp    x1, #0
0x1200e5050:  b.ne   0xc
0x1200e5054:  add    sp, x28, #8
0x1200e5058:  br     x16
0x1200e505c:  mov    lr, x1
0x1200e5060:  ldr    x0, [x28, #8]
0x1200e5064:  add    x1, x28, #16
0x1200e5068:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x1200e506c:  add    x2, x2, #8
0x1200e5070:  mov    x3, x2
0x1200e5074:  ldr    x4, [x3]
0x1200e5078:  add    x3, x3, #8
0x1200e507c:  cmp    x4, #0
0x1200e5080:  b.ne   0xfffffffffffffff4
0x1200e5084:  br     x16

Comment: You might try a clean build command-shift-option-k

Comment: Tx! Wil do and give feedback

Comment: Worked for me. I love that this was fixed with a magic combination of key-presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @possen.. he suggested :
You might try a clean build command-shift-option-k

It worked perfectly. Much Appreciated!!!